# VBA - Remove rows from XLSX where particular text can be found within a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm super new to VBA and hoping I could get some help please ... I'm looking for a succinct way to remove rows from a sheet via Macro and the VBA samples I've tried I cant get to work. I'm hoping it's something simple :)

The macro would remove a row that DOES NOT contain a specific values (from a specific column) from within an array. I sort of had it working, and full disclosure, I've borrowed code from other examples. The latest sample I'm working with just deletes everything, the other sample I was working with deleted Acro32.exe, but kept everything else. So not yet arrived at a solution.

Background: I have a CSV output from an application auditing tool, which spits out tonnes of app data from various computers. That CSV data will be copied into my master 'reporting' spreadsheet. I am only interested in reviewing and keeping data about specific applications, namely Chrome.exe, Firefox.exe, Acro32.exe and Winword.exe. The application name is always found in Column F. So, any cell contents found in Column F, that DOES NOT contain a value in an array, that entire row needs to be deleted. Ideally :) and the remaining rows will only include apps I'm interested in as defined in the array.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal rngToCheck As Range) As Long

    Dim rngLast As Range

    Set rngLast = rngToCheck.Find(what:="*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

    If rngLast Is Nothing Then
        GetLastRow = rngToCheck.Row
    Else
        GetLastRow = rngLast.Row
    End If

End Function

Sub Apps_Formatting()

    Dim varList As Variant
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngCounter As Long
    Dim rngToCheck As Range, rngFound As Range
    Dim rngToDelete As Range, rngDifferences As Range
    Dim blnFound As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
    lngLastRow = GetLastRow(.Cells)

        'we don't want to delete our header row
        Set rngToCheck = .Range("A2:A" & lngLastRow)
    End With

    If lngLastRow > 1 Then

        With rngToCheck

            'any Cell in Column F that contains one of these values are KEPT
            'and if not found in cell, then the entire row is deleted. 

            varList = VBA.Array("Chrome.exe", "Firefox.exe", "Acro32.exe")

            For lngCounter = LBound(varList) To UBound(varList)

                Set rngFound = .Find( _
                                        what:=varList(lngCounter), _
                                        Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                        searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                                        searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                                        MatchCase:=True)

                'check if we found a value we want to keep
                If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then

                    blnFound = True

                    'if there are no cells with a different value then
                    'we will get an error
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set rngDifferences = .ColumnDifferences(Comparison:=rngFound)
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    If Not rngDifferences Is Nothing Then
                        If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                            Set rngToDelete = rngDifferences
                        Else
                            Set rngToDelete = Application.Intersect(rngToDelete, rngDifferences)
                        End If
                    End If

                End If

            Next lngCounter
        End With

        If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
            If Not blnFound Then rngToCheck.EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on this thread, should someone else benefit, the code below was provided and worked really well.

```
Sub a1077712b()
'https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1077712-vba-remove-rows-xlsx-where-particular-text-can-found-within-cell.html
Dim i As Long, r As Range
Dim va As Variant, arr As Variant, flag As Boolean
arr = Array("Chrome.exe", "Firefox.exe", "Acro32.exe", "Winword.exe")
Set r = Range("F2", Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp))
va = r

For i = 1 To UBound(va, 1)
    flag = False
        For Each x In arr
            If InStr(1, va(i, 1), x, 1) > 0 Then flag = True: Exit For
        Next
    If flag = False Then va(i, 1) = ""
Next

r = va
r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```